# Yii ConditionalValidator Not Working

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to set a field as reuired only when another field selected value **not equal to 11.**
I have tried this example

```
array('role', 'ext.YiiConditionalValidator',
                        'if' => array(
                            array('role', 'compare', 'compareValue'=>"11"),
                        ),
                        'then' => array(
                            array('company_id', 'required'),
                        ),
                    ),
                    ),
```

I tried downloading new ConditionalValidator.

And even tried custom condition:

```
public function checkEndDate($attributes,$params)
{


         $this->addError('company_id','Error Message');

}
    public function rules() { 

      return array( 
    array('company_id', 'checkEndDate') 
     ); 
   }
```

But it all shows error. Any simple way to solve this?.

Comment: As you defined, when role is equal to 11 then company_id is required. It's wrong with your purpose: "I am trying to set a field as reuired only when another field selected value not equal to 11"

Answer (score 0):

Why not using scenarios? If you're creating/editing model with 'customer_type=active' you can before hand create it with special scenario:

```
$model = new MyModel(MyModel::SCENARIO_ACTIVE);
```

and then define your rules including scenario:

```
array('birthdate, city', 'required', 'on' => MyModel::SCENARIO_ACTIVE),
array('city', 'in', 'range' => array("sao_paulo", "sumare", "jacarezinho"), 'on' => MyModel::SCENARIO_ACTIVE)
```

If you don't like this way, you can always very simply create your own validator.

In rules:

```
array('customer_type', 'myCustomValidator'),
```

In the model class:

```
function myCustomValidator(){
   if($this->customer_type == 'active'){
      ...
      if($error){
         $this->addError(...);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please read my question once more. I did edit it. Second way i tried and failed. First one i couldn't understand. Could you explain?

Comment: I don't see any checks in your validator (checkEndDate). It just always adds error.

Comment: Even without any checks my function dont add an error. That is the issue.

Comment: Then you do something wrong. You can send me the whole model's code and maybe your controller's part, where you call the model.